# Specifying relative frequency in barplot to correspond to specific year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a dataset that contains data on authorship of scientific articles in a medical speciality in the years 2013, 2016, 2019, and 2022. I am interested in creating a single bar plot that shows the proportion of female authors compared to male authors in those specific years. So far when I create a barplot it gives me the overall proportion from the combined years, I am wondering if there is a way in ggplot to specify that I want the relative frequency to be year specific.

```
My code so far is below

ggplot(aes(x=`First Author`, fill = Year)) + 
  ggtitle("Proportion of First Authorship by Sex For the Years 2013, 2016, 2019, & 2022") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position="dodge") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=10)) + 
  xlab("Author Sex") + ylab("Relative Frequency")
```

Comment: If you could `dput( )` the head of your dataframe so we can see the structure and some values it would make answering this more useful to you